# XPath extracted from Chrome only works for first TR-element in .NET

Tags: vb.net, xpath, html-agility-pack

Could someone help me to solve my problem in the following situation:

I try to get the 3. text "Sangria Vinyl Lyrics" from this webpage:
http://www.metrolyrics.com/pharrell-williams-lyrics.html

Thanks to Google Chrome I found the following XPath to extract it:
`//*[@id='popular']/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/a`
If I try to use this XPath in a Addon like [XPath Helper](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xpath-helper/hgimnogjllphhhkhlmebbmlgjoejdpjl), it works for every element that I search with `tr[1...to...65]`

If I copy & paste this XPath to my .NET code and installed HtmlAgilityPack, I get just "nothing".
Strangely, a modified XPath (`/tr[1]`) to get the 1. text ("Happy Lyrics") is the only one that I get perfectly working, returning "Happy Lyrics".

Is there something special about XPath, element indexes and HtmlAgilityPack in .NET?

My code so far:

```
Dim doc As HtmlDocument = New HtmlWeb().Load("http://www.metrolyrics.com/pharell-williams-lyrics.html")
Dim div As HtmlNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id='popular']/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/a")
```

I tried it even with the "full path XPath" like

```
(/html[1]/body[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[3]/td[2]/a)
```

but with the same result. It works in the Addon but not in .NET

Any idea, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Inspect your document nodes one buy one, if I were to guess now without looking, the "tbody" doesn't exist in htmlagilitypack so you need to remove that.

Comment: @CruleD Thanks. But why should it work for the first entry (if "tbody" doesn't exist) but not for the following ones?

Comment: Just inspect it an look how HAP is reading it an fix the path and you are done. Sometimes browser preview is not the same as when downloading html.